# How to inherit a typical Tensorflow model class to reuse most graph building code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Typical tensorflow model class looks like this:

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        build()
    def build(self):
        self.x = tf.placeholder()
        self.y = f(self.x)
        self.z = g(self.y)
```

If we need a slight modification (ie, change `self.y=f(self.x)` to `slef.y=h(self.x)`), we would really like to inherit this `Model` class and add some code to do this.

However, once the `build` function was called, a complete graph is built. Overriding an attribute won't change the graph structure. Is there any way to do this work neatly?

Answer (score 1):

You could parametrize `f` and `g` (or whatever you have) and pass them in the constructor:

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, f=default_f, g=default_g):
        self.f = f
        self.g = g
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        self.x = tf.placeholder()
        self.y = self.f(self.x)
        self.z = self.g(self.y)
```

Or you can make them overridable class-level variables to avoid the constructor's signature getting bloated, but then you can't implicitly call `.build()` in the constructor:

```
class Model:
    f = default_f
    g = default_g

    def build(self):
        self.x = tf.placeholder()
        self.y = self.f(self.x)
        self.z = self.g(self.y)

# ...

m = Model()
m.f = some_other_f
m.build()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This idea also came up to me. However, function `f` and `g` are always tensorflow operations. If we wrap all the operations we use as class methods, there would be too much work to do.